# GWT change main panel from other class

Tags: constructor, panel

i have a class with the entry point and the onModuleLoad. That class have a getter for the panel `public void sethauptPanel(Composite composite) {
        hauptPanel.clear();
        hauptPanel.add(composite);
    }`

but i need to send an object from my class to change it

```
MenuItem anmelden = new MenuItem(konstanten.anmelden(), new Command() {

        @Override
        public void execute() {

        sethauptPanel(new AdminLoginView(!!!!this!!!));
        }
    });
```

I try this, but than he have the Command. I try classname classname = this.

But i can't change the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use className.this

So if your class is named : MainPanel

you should use : new AdminLoginView(MainPanel.this);